# Find the maximum possible value

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, max

Given the first and the last integer of an array, **a** and **b**, and the size of the array -- **n**, where `n-1 >= |a-b|`.
The difference between the adjacent integers in the array does not exceed 1. 
Among all the possible arrays that satisfy the aforementioned conditions, find the maximum value of the number between the first and the last integer (excluding the first and the last integer that are given).

```
Example 1:
a = 3, b = 3, n = 5
Some possible arrays:
[3, 4, 5, 4, 3]
[3, 2, 1, 2, 3]
[3, 4, 4, 4, 3]
...
The maximum value is 5.

Example 2:
a = 5, b = 6, n = 5
Some possible arrays:
[5, 5, 5, 5, 6]
[5, 5, 6, 7, 6]
[5, 6, 7, 6, 6]
[5, 6, 7, 7, 6]
...
The maximum value is 7.

Example 3:
a = 8, b = 5, n = 4
[8, 7, 6, 5] -- the only array that can be formed
The maximum value is 7 (8 does not count since it is the first number that has been given).

Example 4:
a = 5, b = 8, n = 4
[5, 6, 7, 8] -- the only array that can be formed
The maximum value is 7 (8 does not count).
```

How to approach this problem? I know how to do it when a == b, but not sure about the other cases.

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like you are simply asking someone else to write your code for you, and your question may be closed because of that. To avoid that happening, could you update your question to show the code you have written so far?

Comment: Binary search in this context seems relevant to me with an acceptable time complexity of O(log(n)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Explanation

Since adjacent integers cannot differ by more than 1, you first need to increment the lower of the end-values `a` and `b` until they are equal.

```
a = 3, b = 3, n = 5
[3, _, _, _, 3]

a = 3, b = 5, n = 5
[3, _, _, _, 5]
[3, 4, _, _, 5]
[3, 4, 5, _, 5]

a = 5, b = 3, n = 5
[5, _, _, _, 3]
[5, _, _, 4, 3]
[5, _, 5, 4, 3]
```

So, you will use 2 spaces for the 2 end-values, plus an addition `|a-b|` spaces to "equalize" the values at larger end-value:

```
remain = n - 2 - Math.abs(a - b)
```

For the rest of the spaces, you need to increment from both sides, so you can only increment `remain / 2` times, *rounding up*:

```
incr = (remain + 1) / 2
```

Which means the highest value possible is the number that is `incr` larger than largest end-value:

```
max = Math.max(a, b) + incr;
```

All combined:

```
max = Math.max(a, b) + (n - Math.abs(a - b) - 1) / 2
```

However, there are 2 special scenarios:

- If n = 2, there will be no values between end-values, so `n <= 2` is not valid, as there can be no answer.
- If there are just enough spaces to reach from lower value to higher value, e.g. `a = 3, b = 7, n = 5: [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]`, that means that the first step above would fail, since we cannot "equalize" the values at larger end-value. In this special case, the highest non-end-value is 1 lower than highest end-value:

```
max = Math.max(a, b) - 1
```

---

#### Solution

So, all-in-all, code to calculate highest non-end-value is:

```
static int max(int a, int b, int n) {
    int extra = (n - Math.abs(a - b) - 1);
    if (n <= 2 || extra < 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    return (extra == 0 ? Math.max(a, b) - 1 : Math.max(a, b) + extra / 2);
}
```

Performance is *O(1)* since the result is a simple calculation, without the need to actually build the array to find the result.

---

#### Test

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    test(3, 3, 5); // max from question: 5
    test(5, 6, 5); // max from question: 7
    test(8, 5, 4); // max from question: 7
    test(5, 8, 4); // max from question: 7
    test(3, 5, 5);
    test(5, 3, 5);
    test(3, 7, 5);
    test(3, 7, 6);
    test(3, 7, 7);
    test(3, 7, 8);
    test(3, 7, 9);
}
static void test(int a, int b, int n) {
    System.out.printf("a = %d, b = %d, n = %d: The maximum value is %d. %s%n",
                      a, b, n, max(a, b, n), Arrays.toString(fill(a, b, n)));
}
static int[] fill(int a, int b, int n) {
    int[] v = new int[n];
    int i = 0, j = n - 1;
    v[i] = a;   v[j] = b;
    for (; v[i] < v[j]; i++)
        v[i + 1] = v[i] + 1;
    for (; v[i] > v[j]; j--)
        v[j - 1] = v[j] + 1;
    for (; i + 1 < j; i++, j--)
        v[i + 1] = v[j - 1] = v[i] + 1;
    return v;
}
```

*Output*

```
a = 3, b = 3, n = 5: The maximum value is 5. [3, 4, 5, 4, 3]
a = 5, b = 6, n = 5: The maximum value is 7. [5, 6, 7, 7, 6]
a = 8, b = 5, n = 4: The maximum value is 7. [8, 7, 6, 5]
a = 5, b = 8, n = 4: The maximum value is 7. [5, 6, 7, 8]
a = 3, b = 5, n = 5: The maximum value is 6. [3, 4, 5, 6, 5]
a = 5, b = 3, n = 5: The maximum value is 6. [5, 6, 5, 4, 3]
a = 3, b = 7, n = 5: The maximum value is 6. [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
a = 3, b = 7, n = 6: The maximum value is 7. [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7]
a = 3, b = 7, n = 7: The maximum value is 8. [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 7]
a = 3, b = 7, n = 8: The maximum value is 8. [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 7]
a = 3, b = 7, n = 9: The maximum value is 9. [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 8, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like homework, so just an idea:

Try to draw a plot of values in array. Note that array with described properties might look like saw teeth, but the largest internal value is possible when plot contains the only peak.

If endpoint difference is too large (your last example), then maximum is at the larger end neigbor, otherwise try to build a plot with the max peak value - note that possible slopes are only -1, +1 (and perhaps single plain step for odd n value)